# Getting Python Errors while running check_mssql_server.py nagios plugin

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm getting these errors while trying to use this Nagios plugin and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I've found no other mention of this plugin error mentioned anywhere.  I tried to email the dev, but haven't gotten a response in nearly a week, so figured I would ask here.  Any help would be appreciated.
Everything seems to be installed properly, as running with a -h returns properly, and using an invalid mssql username or password both return the expected login errors from the mssql server.  Using an incorrect instance name also returns a connection error as well.

```
[/usr/local/nagios/libexec]=>/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_server.py -H <hidden> -U <hidden> -P <hidden> --instance=D001 --deadlocks -w 90 -c 95
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_server.py", line 465, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_server.py", line 431, in main
execute_query(mssql, options, host)
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_server.py", line 444, in execute_query
mssql_query.do(mssql)
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_server.py", line 283, in do
self.run_on_connection(connection)
File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mssql_server.py", line 269, in run_on_connection
self.query_result = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: Did you manually check if the query returns something? Read how [fetchone] works.(http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) This should be a good point to start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I checked to be sure it worked from command-line using tsql.  The issue seems to be in running queries from within the script, but I still have no idea why.  Connection seems fine, but checking a rowcount of even a simple mathematical query returns "-1".  After 2 days of messing with this, I think I've found another solution.  I'm still perplexed at what the root cause of this is though.